# MVC for Dedicated Host? What does it mean?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dedicated-server

I use PHP to develop web pages. I'm not newbie and I'm fully familiar with MVC structure. Today I queried from my data center about their Dedicated Hosting Services. They presented a bunch of info on it, and next to it, the operator insisted (in email) that they do not support MVC.

Now, it is a question for me what does it mean to support MVC? (I have asked them but the reply would for sure be sent the next working day (tomorrow, GMT 3.30+).

I'm totally confused and I need immediately to know about since it is been already too late for me to talk to the client so please take this into account.

Does he mean ASP.NET MVC? If so, I had asked them about PHP Dedicated server

Comment: I suspect the person whom you talked to is not qualified to answer your question. If they support `PHP`, the `MVC` structure should not be additionally available. That is, if they have a somewhat recent version of `PHP`.

Comment: `MVC` is simply a software pattern, it can be executed with any language, they have no clue what they are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a design pattern that can be implemented in many languages including PHP, ASP, NodeJs, etc:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

If they have PHP enabled, then by default they have MVC enabled (well it is not something enabled but created). You shouldn't have the need to install new extensions to have MVC. It uses pure PHP (and whatever backend you choose: mysql, mssql, etc..)

You have the option of creating a new MVC structure (Framework) or using existing ones, some of the top of my head:

- Zend
- Codeigniter

A tutorial I found on Google for making your own MVC:

http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Comment: so my question is that it is not related to MVC since MVC is a pattern creatable using some strategies. No need for any extra extension. yes? Unless the person is talking of some Apache setting which then is another story

Comment: No extra extensions are needed.

Comment: Also no extra Apache settings are needed. Default settings that have PHP enabled should be sufficient.